# Stripe webhook: Getting 404 when make payment from other server

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have multi servers for my app, but only one Stripe account.
I want to use the stripe webhooks, but when I make a payment from server X the events are triggered to all webhooks which listen to `payment_intent.success` and the webhook which connects to the server which payment made from return 200, and everything is ok.
but the others events which call the other servers return a 404 error not found.
there is an option to avoid the 404 without creating multi `stripe accounts` for each server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Stripe account has multiple a webhook endpoints listening to the `payment_intent.success` even, then **all** `payment_intent.success` will be sent to **all** your webhook enpoints.

In order to dispatch the `payment_intent.success` event to different URLs, I see three main options:

- Create a single webhook endpoint on your account, listening to `payment_intent.success`. Then by looking at the event payload, your code can forward the events to the relevant server.
- Create multiple webhook endpoints on your account, all listening to `payment_intent.success` and using different URLs. Then by looking at the event payload, each server should be able to tell wether to process the event or ignore it. In both cases the servers should return a 200 response.
- Use multiple Stripe accounts with one webhook endpoint each, all listening to `payment_intent.success` and using different URLs.